# Reducing Timer In Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to implement the below action in Jmeter

while(callAPIVariable and Timer is less than 30 seconds)
    -- call the API
    -- extract the response
    -- If  --> the response is "Still waiting to finish" then do nothing.
    -- Else --> Validate the response  ---> set callAPIVariable to false

I need to loop the while loop till 30 seconds or till callAPIVariable is set to false

I can implement the while loop and all the functions , but i am not able to figure out how to add the timer to the while loop

Comment: Did you tried my solution? Simply Right Click -> Insert Parent -> Runtime Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) before the While Controller and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.putObject('start', System.currentTimeMillis())
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   ```
2. Use the following expression as the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)'s condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('callAPIVariable').equals('true') && (System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.getObject('start') as long) < 30000)),)}
   ```

That's it, the above setup allow the While Controller to loop until `callApiVariable` value is `true` or 30 seconds pass (whatever comes the first)

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all the JMeter Variables in current thread (virtual user) context. Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more details on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for Groovy scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can add as a parent [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) with Runtime set as 30

> Runtime Controller controls how long its children how long its children will run. Controller will run its children until configured Runtime(s) is exceeded.

Simply right click your While Controller -> Insert Parent -> Logic Controller -> Runtime Controller